# Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I was trying to link the username of logged in user with his age but I'm getting the below error. can anybody help me out? Just help me insert the username with the age, please.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class loggedInUser could not be converted to string
```

here is the insert query:

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
require_once("models/config.php");
securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (username, Age) VALUES (?, ?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("ss",  $username, $age);

$stmt->execute();


$stmt->close();

mysqli->close();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and here is what I have inside `config.php`:

```
<?php
require_once("db-settings.php"); //Require DB connection

//Retrieve settings
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name, value
FROM ".$db_table_prefix."configuration");   
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $value);

while ($stmt->fetch()){
$settings[$name] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}
$stmt->close();

//Set Settings
$emailActivation = $settings['activation']['value'];;
$mail_templates_dir = "models/mail-templates/";
$websiteName = $settings['website_name']['value'];
$websiteUrl = $settings['website_url']['value'];

$emailAddress = $settings['email']['value'];
$resend_activation_threshold = $settings['resend_activation_threshold']['value'];
$emailDate = date('dmy');
$language = $settings['language']['value'];
$template = $settings['template']['value'];

$default_hooks = array("#WEBSITENAME#","#WEBSITEURL#","#DATE#");
$default_replace = array($websiteName,$websiteUrl,$emailDate);

if (!file_exists($language)) {
$language = "models/languages/en.php";
}

if(!isset($language)) $langauge = "models/languages/en.php";

//Pages to require
require_once($language);
require_once("class.mail.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
require_once("class.newuser.php");
require_once("funcs.php");

session_start();

//Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if(isset($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]))
{
$loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
}

?>
```

Comment: it is the in which I have the insert query

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you just tell everybody, which variable is used to store the `loggedInUser`-object and which line is line 33.

Comment: To make it easier I just removed styling stuff..that's is why it says on line 33..I will edit it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what properties your loggedInUser object has, but try something like this

```
$user = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"]; // I think this returns an object - loggedInUser
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (username, Age) VALUES (?, ?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("ss",  $user->userName, $age); //or $user->getUsername()
```

Comment: now it doesn't show any error but it isn't inserting to database

Comment: thanks i just changed UserName to username and I was ready to go...many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

At some point - I can't see where in your code, though - you are treating an object as a string. There are a couple of ways around this, depending on what you're trying to do:

- Use a `__toString()` magic method in the `$loggedInUser` class
- Get a string property from the `$loggedInUser` class and deal with that. e.g. `$loggedInUser->getName()`

Comment: @alte It being StackOverflow, it makes more sense to work it out in the answer. Do you know what properties and/or methods the `$loggedInUser` class has? Trying doing `print_r($loggedInUser)`.

Comment: you know what as I'm new I know it's not gonna work whatever I try..If I know how to do this it shouldn't take me 2days to figure this out...I'm still stuck at this without any luck...